# Falling Image with Delay

Tags: ios

Guys I need to know how can I show a image falling 7 seconds up to down after game load?

This is my current code:

on `.h` file

```
IBOutlet UIImageView *CloudDrop;
NSTimer *timer;

-(void)CloudDropCode;
```

on `.m` file

```
-(void)CloudDropCode{
    // Drop Cloud Images Animation
    CloudDrop.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"CloudDrop2.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"CloudDrop.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"CloudDrop2.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"CloudDrop.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"CloudDrop2.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"CloudDrop.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"CloudDrop2.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"CloudDrop.png"],nil];

    [CloudDrop setAnimationRepeatCount:1];
    CloudDrop.animationDuration = 0.1;
    [CloudDrop startAnimating];

    // Drop Cloud Ramdom Position
    CloudDrop.center = CGPointMake(CloudDrop.center.x, CloudDrop.center.y +2);
    if (CloudDrop.center.y > 590){
        ramdomPosition = arc4random() %266;
        ramdomPosition = ramdomPosition +54;

        CloudDrop.center = CGPointMake(ramdomPosition, -40);
        dropCloudUsed = NO;

    // Time to Drop Cloud Down Again
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:7.0]];

        CloudDrop.hidden = NO;
    }
}
```

And this in the `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.03 target:self selector:@selector(CloudDropCode)userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Right now, the image falls when the game are load. I'm trying to fall the image 10 seconds after game load. Any Idea or suggestion? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please note that this site is not a "give me the code" site. This site is for helping people that have done their research, tried something, but need some help to work out some issues. Please click the help link above and read about how to ask a proper question.

Comment: If you have tried something and it isn't working properly then update your question with the relevant code. Describe in detail what issues you are having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define variables:

```
CloudDrop.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"CloudDrop2.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"CloudDrop.png"],nil];

NSUInteger currentIndex = 0;
```

Repeat next method 7 times

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
    //Update there. get next image by index and realize animation
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    if (currentIndex == 0) 
        currentIndex++;
    else 
        currentIndex = 0;
}];
```

Implementing alternate function call for its completion by yourself.